# Android - What happen when getCurrentFocus().clearFocus()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have some trouble with EditText or other input/picker from not my current view/fragment who pop in. My new fragment call EditText or picker from passed fragment when he is create.

I know way to fix this. I can use some dummies view with `requestFocus()` on.
Or sometimes (And that the problem) on `activity.getCurrentFocus().clearFocus();`
But for the last one look like to failed 1/2.

So here is my question : How works `getCurrentFocus()`, did he check only current activity view or child too as fragment? Why this isn't working every time?

If anyone got a lead with this, will be thankful :D

Comment: Is your problem that the view that gained focus is different each time?

Comment: The problem is that the view who get the focus is a view from an old fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the view that gained focus is different each time you can try something like this:

```
View current = getCurrentFocus();
if (current != null) {
current.clearFocus();
}
```

---

If using **clearFocus()** doesn't work as you found, you can:

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/my_layout" 
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true" ...>
```

to the very top level Layout View (a linear layout). To remove focus from all Buttons/EditTexts etc, you can then just do

```
LinearLayout myLayout = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
myLayout.requestFocus();
```

---

**From the docs**

> When a View clears focus the framework is trying to give focus to the first focusable View from the top. Hence, if this View is the first from the top that can take focus, then all callbacks related to clearing focus will be invoked after which the framework will give focus to this view.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what i ask (CF question : "I know way to fix this"). I don't want the way to fix this. I know use a dummy view or getCurrentFocus. I why the first one doesn't work every time.

Comment: Thanks ! I will investigate more :)